# How to work with javascript data objects? How to access the entries by variables?

Tags: javascript, php, json, object, multidimensional-array

I passed a multidimensional array via php to javascript:

```
var my_javascript_var = <?php echo json_encode($my_php_var); ?>;
```

But now i don't know how to access the entries. I tried my_javascript_var['first-level-entry'] and my_javascript_var->first-level-entry but it always return undefined. I was reading some documentations and stuff but surprisingly I didnt find anything that helped. It seems to be a simple problem. So anybody knows the answer?

My intention is to create a pop-up-video when someone clicks on a thumbnail in a list . The list item has the id of the video. So depending on which thumbnail is clicked i get the id of the clicked list item with

```
$('#clips li').click(function () {
     var clip_id = $(this).children().attr('id');
});
```

I want to compare that variable with an object entry and get the video url out of the object. Unfortunately I failed so far. Hope some of you guys will have a tip for me ;)

Regards

Comment: Show `$my_php_var` definition.

Comment: Post at least a sampling of what the result of the `json_encode` looks like. This is a JavaScript problem but those of us unfamiliar with PHP won't be much help if you don't give us the JavaScript in question.

Comment: As i said: It's just an object with ids in the first level, an links to videos and poster images in the level below). The IDs and links can vary. Looks like this in the top level: [Object { 1429={...}}, Object { 9041={...}}] Below it is like: Object { thumbnail="http:...", mainthumbnail="http:...", mp4url="http:...", more...}

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not have such a thing as a "multidimensional array", if through `json_encode` it becomes an *Array of Arrays* then you need to access via indices, i.e.

```
var my_javascript_var = [
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['c', 'd']
];
my_javascript_var[1][0]; // "c"
```

Comment: oh thank you! that's really impractical to me and makes my work more difficult :( So there is no way to transform it into a kind of multidimensional array? Or at least a method to search the variable in the json object and get the entries of the lower levels?

Comment: It depends what you're serialising - List of lists (which the above is) may not be ideal but you can always serialise objects with properties to get something like... `{'Something': [1, 2, 3], 'SomethingElse': [4,5,6], 'OrEven': {'Sub1': 7, 'Sub2': 8, 'Sub3': 'etc...'}}`. That would

Comment: Ah i see. I just want to get back the 2 objects in the highest level of my json which are for example [Object { 1429={...}}, Object { 9041={...}}] - I would need these two in an array without all the sub-objects. Would be that form: [1429, 9041] - so is there maybe a function that would do that?

Comment: Interpreted in _JavaScript_ `[Object { 1429={...}}, Object { 9041={...}}]` means an _Array_ with `2` items (at indices `0` and `1`), item `0` is an _Object_ with one key, `1429`, and item `1` is another _Object_ with one key, `9041`. If you don't already know what the keys will be in the _Objects_, you'll have to use `Object.keys` or some similar method to get the list of keys on an _Object_ and iterate over that (which will be like iterating over another Array)